# Captcha Works on PHP 7.2 but not 7.4

Tags: php, captcha

So I have a captcha that works on PHP 7.2 but not 7.4 or higher.

What can I do to be able to upgrade my site to PHP 7.4 or 8.0 so that my captch will work.

What happens is that the captcha image shows up, but the characters to solve the captcha do not show at all, thus my customers can not submit the form.

This is my page
/home/sitename/public_html/xthm/wp-content/themes/x-child/nc.php

This is the code

```html
<?php
session_start();
//You can customize your captcha settings here
 
$captcha_code = '';
$captcha_image_height = 50;
$captcha_image_width = 130;
$total_characters_on_image = 6;
 
//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid all confusing characters and numbers (For example: l, 1 and i)
$possible_captcha_letters = 'bcdfhjkmnpqrstvwxyz23456789';
$captcha_font = 'monofont.ttf';
 
$random_captcha_dots = 30;
$random_captcha_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color = "0x142864";
$captcha_noise_color = "0x142864";
 
 
$count = 0;
while ($count < $total_characters_on_image) { 
$captcha_code .= substr(
 $possible_captcha_letters,
 mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_captcha_letters)-1),
 1);
$count++;
}
 
$captcha_font_size = $captcha_image_height * .65;
$captcha_image = @imagecreate(
 $captcha_image_width,
 $captcha_image_height
 );
 
/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate(
 $captcha_image,
 255,
 255,
 255
 );
 
$array_text_color = hextorgb($captcha_text_color);
$captcha_text_color = imagecolorallocate(
 $captcha_image,
 $array_text_color['red'],
 $array_text_color['green'],
 $array_text_color['blue']
 );
 
$array_noise_color = hextorgb($captcha_noise_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate(
 $captcha_image,
 $array_noise_color['red'],
 $array_noise_color['green'],
 $array_noise_color['blue']
 );
 
/* Generate random dots in background of the captcha image */
for( $count=0; $count<$random_captcha_dots; $count++ ) {
imagefilledellipse(
 $captcha_image,
 mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
 2,
 3,
 $image_noise_color
 );
}
 
/* Generate random lines in background of the captcha image */
for( $count=0; $count<$random_captcha_lines; $count++ ) {
imageline(
 $captcha_image,
 mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
 mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
 $image_noise_color
 );
}
 
/* Create a text box and add 6 captcha letters code in it */
$text_box = imagettfbbox(
 $captcha_font_size,
 0,
 $captcha_font,
 $captcha_code
 ); 
$x = ($captcha_image_width - $text_box[4])/2;
$y = ($captcha_image_height - $text_box[5])/2;
imagettftext(
 $captcha_image,
 $captcha_font_size,
 0,
 $x,
 $y,
 $captcha_text_color,
 $captcha_font,
 $captcha_code
 );
 
/* Show captcha image in the html page */
// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($captcha_image); //showing the image
imagedestroy($captcha_image); //destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['string'] = $captcha_code;
 
function hextorgb ($hexstring){
  $integar = hexdec($hexstring);
  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($integar >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($integar >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $integar);
    }
?>
```

Comment: For a start, run a static analyzer on your code and understand each warning it issues. If that doesn't work, extract a [mcve] (properly formatted) and e.g. include that in a question here. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You're probably missing some image libraries in 7.4